# Como unir 2 listas em um unica Matriz?

Tags: python

Faça um programa que crie dois vetores, usando listas e, receba 6 números inteiros em cada um dos vetores. Por fim, o programa deverá criar uma matriz 3x4 a partir da intercalação dos dois vetores.

Essa intercalação se dará da seguinte forma:

Captura dois elementos do vetor1 e coloca na matriz

Captura dois elementos do vetor2 e coloca na matriz

Repete até preencher a matriz

Como faço essa intercalação ?

```
    vet1 = []
    vet2 = []
    vet3 = []

    print ('Informe os valores do primeiro vetor')

    for i in range(0, 3):
        vet1.append(int(input('Informe um numero: ')))

    print ('Informe os valores do segundo vetor')

    for i in range(0, 3):
        vet2.append(int(input('Informe um numero: ')))

    for i in range(0, 3):
        vet3.append(vet1[i]) 
        vet3.append(vet2[i])

     print (vet3)
```

esse foi o codigo q fiz pra testar

Comment: Tem que mostrar o que você já fez, se a dúvida é a intercalação mostre o código para criar os vetores

Comment: editei com o codigo

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 1):

Depois de obter os dois vetores de seis elementos, uma possibilidade é iterar simultaneamente por ambos os vetores, ao passo de dois elementos, exclusive até seus últimos elementos, iterando pelo [intervalo](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) de indices extraindo [fatias](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/glossary.html#term-slice) de ambos os vetores para compor o resultado.

O intervalo ou tipo [`range(start ,stop [ ,step ])`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) representa uma sequência imutável de números e é comumente usado para percorrer um número determinado de vezes em um laço [`for`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for), onde:

- `start`: é o inicio do intervalo. Se omitido seu valor na falta é 0.
- `stop`: é o fim do intervalo.
- `step`: é o passo qual os elementos do intervalo são incrementados. Se omitido seu valor na falta é 1.

Concatene duas listas com o [operador `+`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) e apense um elemento a uma lista usando o método [`list.append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20append#more-on-lists).

```
vet1 = [1,2,5,6,9,10]    #Primeiro vetor de seis elementos.
vet2 = [3,4,7,8,11,12]   #Segundo vetor de seis elementos.
vet3 = []

#Para i variando no intervalo [0,6[ a cada 2 elementos...
for i in range(0,6,2):  
  vet3.append(vet1[i:i+2] + vet2[i:i+2])    #...concatena as fatias vet1[i:i+2] e vet2[i:i+2] em um único vetor e apensa a vet3. 
 
print(vet3)
#[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/Q9UoTm)</sup>

Ou use o código equivalente aproveitando-se de [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
vet1 = [1,2,5,6,9,10]    #Primeiro vetor de seis elementos.
vet2 = [3,4,7,8,11,12]   #Segundo vetor de seis elementos.

#Uma matriz formado pelas concatenações de vet1[i:i+2] e vet2[i:i+2] onde cada elemento i ∈ [0,6[ | Δi=2.
vet3 = [vet1[i:i+2] + vet2[i:i+2] for i in range(0,6,2)]

print(vet3)
#[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/yitd2A)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Acho que esse código pode te ajudar:

```
def intercalacao(vetor_1=None, vetor_2=None):
    num_linhas = 3
    num_colunas = 4
    # cria matriz 3x4
    matriz = [[0 for i in range(num_colunas)] for j in range(num_linhas)]

    # intercala os valores dos vetores
    # montando assim a matriz 
    for i in range(num_linhas):
        for j in range(num_colunas):
            # j for divisivel por 2
            if j % 2 == 0:
                # remove o primeiro elemento do vetor
                # e a posicao da matriz recebe seu valor
                matriz[i][j] = vet_1.pop(0)
                #
            else:
                matriz[i][j] = vet_2.pop(0)

    return matriz


if __name__ == '__main__':

    vet_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    vet_2 = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

    matriz = intercalacao(vetor_1=vet_1, vetor_2=vet_2)
    print(matriz)
```

Answer (score -2):

pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
vet1 = []
vet2 = []
vet3 = []

print ('Informe os valores do primeiro vetor')

for i in range(0, 3):
    vet1.append(int(input('Informe um numero: ')))

print ('Informe os valores do segundo vetor')

for i in range(0, 3):
    vet2.append(int(input('Informe um numero: ')))

vet3.append(vet1)
vet3.append(vet2)

print(vet3)
```

minha saída:

```
adryan@notebook:~/Python$ python3 teste.py 
Informe os valores do primeiro vetor
Informe um numero: 3
Informe um numero: 2
Informe um numero: 4
Informe os valores do segundo vetor
Informe um numero: 5
Informe um numero: 6
Informe um numero: 3
[[3, 2, 4], [5, 6, 3]]
```